# In Accurev, how can I send files from a stream to a workspace in batch?

Tags: accurev

I have 2 streams in Accurev, call them stream A and stream B. They share a very ancient common ancestor. I also have a workspace A and workspace B if that matters.

In stream B, over time, various libraries, tools, code, etc. have been added. All of these elements were never added to stream A.

Now, I am tasked with bringing all the libraries, tools, code, etc. from stream B into stream A. Here lies the problem:

If I "change pallet" from stream B into workspace A, the missing files simply do not show up. They are not part of the change pallet for some reason.

If I "diff by files" between stream B and workspace A, I see some of the missing files, but many of them are missing from the diff. Furthermore, I would like to simply right click on a missing file and choose "send to workspace", but the option is nowhere to be found, making this diff completely useless for my needs.

Ultimately my question is this: How can I see a list of files that are present in stream B but not present in stream A, and how can I easily add those files to stream A?

Thanks,